# Stuck matching output shape of Conv2DNet to expected tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement the model presented [here](https://nicholastsmith.wordpress.com/2017/10/14/deep-learning-ocr-using-tensorflow-and-python/) in Keras. I've more or less figured the Keras model equivalent to be:

```
inputShape = (32, 640, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(NC//2, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Conv2D(NC, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,1), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(NC, kernel_size=(8,5), strides=(8,5), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5), padding='same'))
model.add(Reshape((-1, MAX_CHAR, NC)))
```

The training data consists of 5000, 32x640 images of randomly generated strings, and is split into two arrays, input `A` and output `Y`. `A` is matrix of images `(NIMG, Height, Width, Channel)`. `Y` is matrix of characters `(NIMG, MAX_CHAR)`.

`MAX_CHAR` is the maximum number of characters in an image, in this case 64. `NC` is the number of possible different characters, 63 in this case.

The problem is, when I run `model.fit(A, Y)` I get:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected reshape_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (5001, 64)
```

That makes sense, seeing as how in the blog post it's said:

> the target matrix is a 3D matrix with the three dimensions
>   corresponding to sample, character, and 1-hot encoding respectively.

I've tried `model.Flatten()` but that leaves me a shape `(4032,)`, way larger than the 64 characters in the training data. I've also tried playing around with the Reshape vector values, to no real avail.

So my question is: am I doing something wrong? Is there something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding or is there a solution that I just can't seem to think of/find?

Comment: As has been stated in the blog post, the `Y` should be a 3D matrix of shape `(NIMG, MAX_CHAR, NC)` and not `(NIMG, MAX_CHAR)`. You need to one-hot encode the characters in `Y`.

Comment: You're right, thanks. My bad for blindly copying code. Got it to work now

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as mentioned in the comments, one-hot encoding the labels (i.e. `Y`) resolved the issue.

*Note: this answer is posted as community wiki as suggested in [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/2099607) of ["Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/2099607).*